# Join multiple paths using os.join.path

Tags: python, path, directory

I am able to execute the following, where it uses each member of the list to create a different path:

```
diagnoses = ['DS','FXS']
path = "Transcripts{dirsep}*{diagnosis}{dirsep}*.txt".format(dirsep=os.sep, diagnosis=diagnoses)
```

However, the following raises an error:

```
path = os.path.join('Transcripts',diagnoses,'*.txt')
```

Can I use `os.path.join` to  get multiple paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you are looking for is to use os.path.join to create the output

```
Transcripts/*['DS', 'FXS']/*.txt
```

you could simply cast your diagnoses list to a string like so.

```
os.path.join('Transcripts', '*'+str(diagnoses), '*.txt')
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use some kind of iteration, like this list comprehension:

```
>>> paths = [os.path.join('Transcripts', diagnose, '*.txt') for diagnose in diagnoses]
>>> paths
['Transcripts\\DS\\*.txt', 'Transcripts\\FXS\\*.txt']
```

Comment: Thanks. The first one *does* work, though, and the `*` works.

Comment: I'm not sure it's answered, as this doesn't address the fact that what I have in the first example works and the `*` operator works

Comment: If what you are looking for is to use os.path.join to create `"Transcripts/*['DS', 'FXS']/*.txt"`, you could simply cast your `diagnoses` list to a string. `os.path.join('Transcripts', '*'+str(diagnoses), '*.txt')`

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks! Could you make it into an answer?